# How to do "grep -rn <pattern> <dir>" -- except some specific files?

Tags: grep

The following command is not working to me:

```
grep -rn --exclude={spec_file1,spec_file2} <pattern> <dir>
```

How do I force `grep` not to search in `spec_file1` and `spec_file2`?

Comment: Show exact command string and its output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out:

`grep -rn --exclude=spec_file1 --exclude=spec_file2 <pattern> <dir>`